# Build error :colors.xml:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: android

this is my first time asking here

I'm using android studio 3.2
Whenever i create a new project or open an old one i get this error in build:

> E:\AndroidProjects\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

and when i open the colors.xml file it contains the following comment

> /** Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.* You may ob

when I tried to change this comment to the usual colors.xml content which is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>


    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>


    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

i had this error

> Android resource compilation failed
>   Output:  E:\AndroidProjects\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml:1: error: not well-formed (invalid token).
>
> Command: C:\Users\New
>   Tech.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\b01082f257a5a2a15bea752c6346e430\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe
>   compile --legacy \
>           -o \
>           E:\AndroidProjects\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
>           E:\AndroidProjects\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml
>   Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #2

and sometimes i get a message that an idea error occurred when i open it i shows the following

> Failed to build java cls class for C:/Users/New Tech/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.0/a134b0cfe9bb44f98b0b3e889cda07923eea9428/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.0.jar!/kotlin/UnsignedKt.class: C:/Users/New Tech/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.0/a134b0cfe9bb44f98b0b3e889cda07923eea9428/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.0.jar!/kotlin/UnsignedKt.class: null

Are these issues related?

Note:I didn't change anything from my prior settings or anything

I searched a lot before asking here and found nothing related to my problem because  I didn't know how to phrase he question

And this is he build.gradle for the app (this app is an example that contains nothing yet)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Also show us your `ic_launcher.xml` inside `mipmap-anydpi-v26` directory. There is some error in that file. And remove the comment inside `colors.xml`.

Comment: when i opened the ic_launcher.xml it had the same comment that i referred to in the question inside the colors.xml

Comment: Ok remove that comment and it should start with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Comment: Let me know if you face any further problem.

Comment: well the problem is that even my .xml files inside the drawable folder are showing the same comment...why is this happening because all my projects have the same issue...some of them I created over a year ago and some are as new as today

Comment: You have to remove this comment from every file. Don't know why it happened but may be moving project cause this issue.

Comment: Ok i will try doing that for now to see if it helps,and I'll keep looking into a solution ...thank you for help

Comment: Are you using Windows and did your computer or Android Studio crash at some point? We've been seeing this happening recently. Try deleting your .gradle/ cache and .android-studio-<version>/ cache in your home directory.

Comment: yes I am using windows 10...and it crashed few days ago...I will try doing that,thanks

Comment: it didn't work :/  gave me the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you've hit a known issue that has affected a lot of people on Windows. It happens if your system is shutdown suddenly or Android Studio is killed. The team is aware of this issue and is working on identifying the cause.

You can follow the progress on https://issuetracker.google.com/119638289

Comment: Thank you very much,I'll keep an eye on it , meanwhile I switched to intellij idea

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I tried a few solutions but nothing worked. Then I tried to start a new project with **Basic Activity** instead of **Empty Activity**, and it worked. No errors and it ran fine, not sure why, but it does fix the problem, for me.

Comment: include library versions in your answer. Also link it with Izabela Orlowska her answer to avoid a low-quality flag.